# MVC4 WebSite 404 Error on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

### Set-up

I have a website built in Visual Studio 2012 using MVC 4 and .NET framework 4.5.

It is being hosted on a Windows 2008 and running IIS7.

I am using a VS2012 "Web Deploy Package" to deploy to the server. I manually copy this to the server and run the install using the web deploy cmd script option /T and then /Y. It all installs fine to the Test folder.

On the Test website in IIS the application pool is pointing to the DefaultAppPool which is set for integrated and pointing to the .Net Framework v4.0.30319

I have created a new Web Site in IIS for the application called Test and defaulted the bindings for port 80 and stopped the default web site that is in IIS.

I've created a new foldeer called Test under wwwroot which is where the Web Deploy script is set to point to, when I created the script I add "Test" as the Site/Application

When I have created the web deploy package on my local machine I am manually copying the zip file and other deploy files (cmd,*.xml) to the remote server

I have run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i on the server and installed .net 4.5 framework and MVC framework components I could see in the Web Platform installer.

### Problem

This website was previously being hosted on Windows Azure and have been able to direct publish to Azure and everything runs fine and when I go to any page it displays as expected.But on the new web server I get a 404 when I go to any page.

Everything seems to be installed as far as I can see on the web server. I was able to stop my website and re-start the default web site and add an index.htm file and that displays fine.

It almost seems like something in the MVC pipeline is not initialising. I'm using the standard Home controller with Index action that comes as part of the VS20102 MVC template as a test and that returns me a 404 when I go to /Home.

I've also tried other endpoints (I have WEB api rest endpoints off /API/* and these are returning 404 errors).

I'm just wondering if there is some basic set-up I've missed. It almost seems like some service is not running correctly and picking up the MVC website.

Comment: have you checked security / permissions? what does they say

Comment: Anything in eventlog? Does the website have all the folders (bin,Views, Scripts etc.) displayed properly in IIS manager?

Comment: Yes the permissions look good and also all the folders are in place that I would expect for an MVC app. I've set-up tracing and looked in the event log as well but can't see anything that helps at the moment.